# MVC Ajax with Dynamic Partial View Creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I create dynamic ajax.actionlinks that will call dynamic partial views.

**For example:**

- I have a page that will generate x number of comments
- Each comment can be voted up or down (individually)
- The number of up votes and down votes are counted into a single integer
- Each comment div will have its own ajax.actionlink
- Each ajax.actionlink will pass to the controller the ID of the comment
- The controller will calculate the total votes and call the partial view to display back into the div with the correct ID.

**What have I done so far:**

- I have been able to create successful ajax.actionlink
- That will call a controller and sum the votes
- That will call the partial view and display the votes

**What is the issue**

- I don't want to hard code 30-100 different ajax.actionlinks to call 30-100 hard coded partial views.

**How can I accomplish this dynamically?**

**Existing Code:**

My ajax.actionlink inside my razor view

```
 @Html.Raw(Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "VoteUp",
                new { UserPostID = @Model.Id },
                        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "CountVote" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]",
                        "<img src=\"/Images/up_32x32.png\" />"))
```

My div inside the same razor view to display the returning results from the partial view.

```
<div id="CountVote" class="postvotes"></div>
```

My controller

```
    public PartialViewResult VoteUp(int UserPostID)
    {
        try
        {
            UserVotes vote = new UserVotes();
            vote.SubmitedVote = 1;
            vote.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
            vote.UserPostID = UserPostID;
            ViewBag.SumVotes = postRepository.InsertUserPostVote(vote);

        }
         catch (Exception e)
        {
            xxx.xxx.xxxx().Raise(e);
        }
        return PartialView("_TotalVotes");
    }
```

And finally my partial view (_TotalVotes.cshtml)

```
@ViewBag.SumVotes
```

Now my main view for Viewpost shows the comments in a loop using the viewbag.

```
foreach (var item in (List<UserComment>)ViewData["Comments"])
            {
                CommentVote = "cv" + i.ToString();
    <div class="postlinewrapper">
        <div class="postvotesframe">
            <div class="postvotes">
                @Html.Raw(Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "VoteUp",
                        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "CountVote" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]",
                        "<img src=\"/Images/up_32x32.png\" />"))
            </div>

            <div id="@CommentVote" class="@CommentVote">0</div>
            <div class="postvotes">
                @Html.Raw(Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "VoteDown",
                        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "CountVote" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]",
                        "<img src=\"/Images/down_32x32.png\" />"))
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postleftbar">
            @Html.Raw(item.Comment)
        </div>
        <div class="postrightbar">
            <div>
                <div class="post_spec">
                    <div class="post_spec_title">Call Sign:  </div>
                    <div class="post_spec_detail">@item.CallSign</div>
                </div>
                <div class="post_spec">
                    <div class="post_spec_title">When:  </div>
                    <div class="post_spec_detail">@item.CommentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
                i += 1;
            }
```

I have implemented the login to increase or decrease votes up and down:

```
 public PartialViewResult VoteUp(int userPostId)
        {
            try
            {
                UserVotes vote = new UserVotes();
                vote.SubmitedVote = 1;
                vote.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
                vote.UserPostID = userPostId;
                ViewBag.SumVotes = postRepository.InsertUserPostVote(vote);

            }
             catch (Exception e)
            {
                xxxx.xxxx.xxxx().Raise(e);
            }
            return PartialView("_TotalVotes");
        }

        public PartialViewResult VoteDown(int userPostId)
        {
            try
            {
                UserVotes vote = new UserVotes();
                vote.SubmitedVote = -1;
                vote.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
                vote.UserPostID = userPostId;
                ViewBag.SumVotes = postRepository.InsertUserPostVote(vote);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                xxx.xxxx.xxxx().Raise(e);
            }
            return PartialView("_TotalVotes");
        }
```

Now all this code works for 1 ajax call just fine, but what I need to is to display separate ajax calls for separate divs dynamically.

Comment: The container (div with ID) is part of the partial view? I'm not sure I understand the question (maybe include example code?)

Comment: No. So the Ajax.Action link will call an Action that in return will call a partial view that will populate a div.

The issue is creating divs and partial views on the fly based on how many are needed. I will post later some sample code.

Comment: you're outgrowing Ajax Helpers. You really want a Javascript MVC language like AngularJS or EmberJS. With a robust templated framework, your viewdata can be couple to JS variables. So the same call to an endpoint to register a vote can also return a vote count. Once you update your vote-count JS variables, your View can reflect the new data without DOM manipulation or loading.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: If your already rendering the comments in the view, why would you call a method to return the view again. Just give each 'vote button' a class name and store the associated comment ID in a `data-` attribute, then handle the `.click()` event and use ajax to pass the ID to a method and in the success function, update the associated vote count value in the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way.

**Main view**

I'm supposing you have a model with a collection property `Comments` of Comment items

```
@model MyNamespace.CommentAndOtherStuff

<ul>
    @foreach(item in Model.Comments)
    {
      <li>
          <a href="@Url.Action("VoteUp", "VoteControllerName", new { UserPostId = item.Id })" 
             class="vote-link"
             data-id="@item.Id">@item.Votes</a><img src="vote.jpg" />
      </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And your controller just returns a class called `VoteResult` as JSON.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VoteUp(int UserPostID)
{
    ...
    var model = new VoteResult
    {
        UserPostID = UserPostID,
        Votes = service.tallyVote(UserPostID)
    };

    return Json(model);
}
```

Now hook all of those up with a jQuery event handler and setup an AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.vote-link").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);  // the link instance that was clicked
        var id = link.attr("data-id");
        var url = link.attr("href");

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post"
        })
        .done(function(result) {
            // JSON result: { UserPostID: 1, Votes: 5 }

            // replace link text
            link.html(result.Votes);
        });
    });

});
```

*But I want a partial view html fagment.*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VoteUp(int UserPostID)
{
    ...
    var model = new VoteResult
    {
        UserPostID = UserPostID,
        Votes = service.tallyVote(UserPostID)
    };

    return PartialView("_TotalVotes", model);
}
```

**_TotalVotes partial**

```
@model MyNamespace.VoteResult

@if (Model.Votes < 0)
{
    <span class="unpopular">@Model.Votes</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="awesome">@Model.Votes</span>
}
```

And adjust the AJAX callback

```
.done(function(result) {
    link.html(result);
});
```

Now you could write a helper for the link fragment but it obfuscates things in my opinion (it's a judgement call). All you really need here is the class name and the data-id which your javascript will bind.

Comment: you mean pass the class id to the controller, so it knows which one to update back?

Comment: The class attribute `vote-link` links your anchor elements to the javascript click handler. The `data-id` attribute holds the id you need to track the specific comment (which your controller action is using to record votes). The `link` variable held the reference to the anchor that triggered the click and the AJAX callback uses `link` to update the correct item.

Comment: The solution was close to your proposal. I had to generate the div css id on the fly and pass the same name to the controller. It was that easy.

But I would have thought about it without your answer. So you get the points.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `Ajax` helpers here seems an unnecessary overhead and I suggest you just use jquery methods to update the DOM. Your current code suggests you might be missing some logic to make a comment voting system work, including indicating what action the user may have already performed. For example (and assuming you want it to work similar to SO), if a user has previously up-voted, then clicking on the up-vote link should decrement the vote count by 1, but clicking on the down-vote link should decrement the vote count by 2 (the previous up-vote plus the new down-vote).

Refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17fj5a0b/) for how this might be styled and behave when clicking the vote elements

Your view model for a comment might look like

```
public enum Vote { "None", "Up", "Down" }
public class CommentVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public Vote CurrentVote { get; set; }
  public int TotalVotes { get; set; }
}
```

and assuming you have a model that contains a collection of comments

```
public class PostVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<CommentVM> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and the associated `DisplayTemplate`

/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CommentVM.cshtml

```
@model CommentVM
<div class="comment" data-id="@Model.ID" data-currentvote="@Model.CurrentVote">
  <div class="vote">
    <div class="voteup" class="@(Model.CurrentVote == Vote.Up ? "current" : null)"></div>
    <div class="votecount">@Model.TotalVotes</div>
    <div class="votedown" class="@(Model.CurrentVote == Vote.Down ? "current" : null)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="commenttext">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Text)</div>
</div>
```

Then in the main view

```
@model PostVM
.... // display some properties of Post?
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Comments)

<script>
  var voteUpUrl = '@Url.Action("VoteUp")';
  var voteDownUrl = '@Url.Action("VoteDown")';
  $('.voteup').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.comment');
    var id = container.data('id');
    var voteCount = new Number(container.find('.votecount').text());
    $.post(voteUpUrl, { id: id }, function(response) {
      if (!response) {
        // oops, something went wrong - display error message?
        return;
      }
      container.find('.votecount').text(response.voteCount); // update vote count
      if (response.voteCount < voteCount) {
        // the user previously upvoted and has now removed it
        container.find('.voteup').removeClass('current');
      } else if (response.voteCount == voteCount + 1) {
        // the user had not previously voted on this comment
        container.find('.voteup').addClass('current');
      } else if (response.voteCount == voteCount + 2) {
        // the user previoulsy down voted
        container.find('.votedown').removeClass('current');
        container.find('.voteup').addClass('current');
      }
    });
  });
  $('.votedown').click(function() {
    ... // similar to above (modify logic in if/elseif blocks)
  });

</script>
```

and the controller method

```
public JsonResult VoteUp(int id)
{
  int voteCount = // your logic to calculate the new total based on the users current vote (if any) for the comment
  return Json(new { voteCount = voteCount });
}
```

Comment: Stephen, thank you for your help. I am going to choose Jasen's answer.